# How do i break string into words at the position of number

Tags: php, string

I have some string data with alphanumeric value. like **us01name, phc01name** and other i.e **alphabates + number + alphabates**.

i would like to get **first alphabates + number** in first string and **remaining on second**.

How can i do it in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
// if statement checks there's at least one match
if(preg_match('/([A-z]+[0-9]+)([A-z]+)/', $string, $matches) > 0){
    $firstbit = $matches[1];
    $nextbit  = $matches[2];
}
```

Just to break the regular expression down into parts so you know what each bit does:

```
(              Begin group 1
  [A-z]+         As many alphabet characters as there are (case agnostic)
  [0-9]+         As many numbers as there are
)              End group 1
(              Begin group 2
  [A-z]+         As many alphabet characters as there are (case agnostic)
)              End group 2
```

Comment: thxn... more descriptive... m using suggestion from anubhava too

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
preg_match('~([^\d]+\d+)(.*)~', "us01name", $m);
var_dump($m[1]); // 1st string + number
var_dump($m[2]); // 2nd string
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(4) "us01"
string(4) "name"
```

Even this more restrictive regex will also work for you:

```
preg_match('~([A-Z]+\d+)([A-Z]+)~i', "us01name", $m);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) on the digits with the pattern capture flag. It returns all pieces, so you'd have to put them back together. However, in my opinion is more intuitive and flexible than a complete pattern regex. Plus, `preg_split()` is underused :)

Code:

```
$str = 'user01jason';
$pieces = preg_split('/(\d+)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($pieces);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => user
    [1] => 01
    [2] => jason
)
```